# series convergence. $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n}+ (-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n}+ (-1)^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}$$
None of convergence tests I know (Leibnitz, Dirichlet, Abel) works becaues of the denominator.

I know that sum of convergent series is convergent too and I tried using this information with no results.

Comment: Are you sure that $n=1$ ?

Comment: I'm so sorry, you're right.
It's n=2

Comment: It would have been funny !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms approach $0$, so it is enough to show that the partial sums 
$$\sum_2^{4q+1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/3}+(-1)^{n(n+1)/2}}$$
converge.

Decompose the above partial sum into two parts: (i) the terms with $n\equiv 1$ or $2$ modulo $4$ and (ii) the terms with $n\equiv 3$ or $4$ modulo $4$. Each part is the partial sum of  an alternating series.

**Remark:** The argument above is not difficult to find: One  writes down the first half-dozen terms or so, and observes the sign pattern.

Comment: I understand your thinking. It turned out that I was on the right way to solve this.
But could you write this in more details and in formal way since I have always problem with that? I'd be very grateful